# My ms-auto is not aligning the contents right inside a div?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-5

The following is my code, but ms-auto is not working at all :

```
<div class="p-5 rounded bg-light text-dark">
  <div class="container row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Copyright © 2021 Ekayanam - All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ms-auto">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ekayanam" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook text-primary fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ekayanam/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram text-danger fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 5...

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? If you're trying to center everything on the page try `mx-auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to push the anchor tags to the right of the column, use `text-end` (Bootstrap 5), or `text-right` (for Bootstrap 4) instead of `ms-auto`.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/dqp03mcz/3/)